# Is it true that $\|(I+A)^{-1}\| \leq \|(I-B)^{-1}\|$ if $|A|<B$?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Is it true that $\|(I+A)^{-1}\|_\infty \leq \|(I-B)^{-1}\|_\infty$ if $|A|<B$?
What if $A$ and $B$ are triangular matrices?

Definition 1: $|A| = [|a_{ij}|]$, absolute value of every entry of $A$.

Definition 2: $A<B$ if for every entry, $a_{ij}<b_{ij}$.

ANY suggestion is appreciated.